# Ruby on Rails 4 - Paperclip + S3 + Devise upload form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm trying to set up avatar uploading to a Devise model, with Paperclip and S3

index.html.haml

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this friend from being saved:
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .field
    = f.label :avatar
    %br
    = f.file_field :avatar
    %br
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Upload avatar'
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

paperclip.rb (the initializer, this is the whole content)

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'http'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] =
    { :bucket => 'secret',
      :access_key_id => 'secret',
      :secret_access_key => 'secret' }
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

index_controller.rb

```
def index
  @user = User.new
end
```

production.rb & development.rb

```
# Nothing to do with paperclip
```

So my problem is: When I'm uploading the image I get a 
Routing Error: uninitialized constant UsersController

I'm pretty new to Rails.
What can I do? Or does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created Users Controller and when you use form_for it use object's own routes.

like in your case it becomes:

```
<form action="/users" method="POST">
```

In Routes it map on:

```
users#create
```

You are checking it in IndexController that's wrong. Your request send on UsersController and on create action. You have to create users controller and create action in it.

users_controller.rb

Like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def create
    @user = User.new
end
end
```